# Using Number Filter in AngularJS ng-style

Tags: angularjs

What is the preferred way of using a number filter in ng-style? I have an image that I want to only be set to a whole number pixel value of height.

```
<img src="ok-button.png" ng-style="{'height': textHeight * 1.888 | number:0}">
```

The above code does not work but reflects what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height property should have mentioned in  pixel so you need to add `px` to indicate it is pixel.

You were using `number` filter which is used to change text to `,` separated currency representation, which would applicable to solve your case.

For rounding pixels you should have define function inside controller which will do `Math.roud` of that value & return it to the view.

**HTML**

```
ng-style="{'height': round(textHeight) + 'px'}"
```

**Code**

```
$scope.round = function(textHeight){
  var result = textHeight * 1.88;
  return Math.roud(result);
}
```